# (PHP, javascript and html) Reading out txt-file nicely

Tags: java, php, html

I have created a php-file which saves it when a user writes something in my form. It is saving the user-input in a txt-file. 
I want to update and show the content of the txt-file for other users on my webpage. 
I am currently using the "echo file_get_contents" but it is showing the input like this:

[{"title":null,"content":null,"username":null,"comment":null}] etc.

Instead I wanted it to be shown in a 'prettier' way. Not just a string of inputs, but making it look like a question with comments and so on.

I hope it makes sense...

Comment: Did you know JavaScript is actually standardized as ECMAScript. It doesn't have Java in the formal name. Because they are totally unrelated languages. Now that you know that, is your question about Java or about JavaScript? Also, where is your code?

Comment: I don't know how to insert my code in here... But I mean javascript

Comment: The code in my file that saves the post: 

<?php
  if(isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
?>
  <h2>Ask your question</h2>

    <form name="nytopslag" action="nytopslag.php" method="POST">
      <table>
        <tr><td>Titel på spørgsmål</td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="text" name="titel"></td></tr><br>

        <tr><td>Uddybende indhold</td></tr><br>
        <tr><td><textarea name="indhold" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Opret"></td></tr>
      </table>
    </form>

<?php } ?>

The code for showing the users inputs:

Comment: <?php
echo file_get_contents('opslag.txt');
?>

Comment: Edit your question. Putting your code in comments was `<?php echo "not very helpful" ?>`